# Error migrating library from rollup to vitejs

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollupjs, preact

## Problem

I have a project let's call it `root` (based on Preact) that relies on a `components` package (based on React):

**Building it using rollup works fine. When I switch `components` to use vitejs to build, `root` fails at runtime** with this error:

```
index.es.js? [sm]:770 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')
    at jsxDEV (index.es.js? [sm]:770:64)
    at jsxWithValidation (index.es.js? [sm]:954:17)
    at jsxWithValidationDynamic (index.es.js? [sm]:992:13)
    at d.RecipesExplorer [as constructor] (index.es.js? [sm]:1915:33)
    at d.O [as render] (index.js:532:14)
    at j (index.js:190:14)
    at w (children.js:137:3)
    at L (index.js:418:4)
    at j (index.js:246:20)
    at w (children.js:137:3)
```

I'm not changing anything in `root` or how it's run. It's built using vitejs as well (in both scenarios).

## Rollup config

Here's the `rollup.config.js` for `components` (this is the build scenario that works without issue):

```
// rollup.config.js for components
import { defineConfig } from 'rollup'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles'

export default defineConfig([
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      // I don't think we need both of these. Keeping them since we had them for now in webpack
      {
        dir: 'dist/esm',
        format: 'es',
      },
      {
        dir: 'dist/cjs',
        format: 'cjs',
      },
    ],
    plugins: [typescript({}), json()],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'],
  }
])
```

## Vitejs config

When I switch to using vitejs, this is the vite config:

```
// vite.config.js for components
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  mode: 'development',
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: false,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    minify: false,
    target: 'modules',
    outDir: './dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'styled-components'],
    },
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/index.ts'),
      formats: ['cjs', 'es'],
      fileName: format => `index.${format}.js`,
    },
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
})
```

## Package.json snippet

Since vitejs and rollup place files in different directories, I change `package.json` as well.

For vitejs:

```
// package.json when configured for vitejs
"name": "components",
...
"exports": {
    ".": {
        "import": "./dist/index.es.js",
        "require": "./dist/index.cjs.js"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "build:rollup": "rollup -c",
},
...
```

For rollup:

```
// package.json when configured for rollup
"name": "components",
...
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/esm/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "build:rollup": "rollup -c",
},
...
```

## Command I'm running & conclusion

When I build `components` using `npm run build` (with vite), I get the above error. When I build with `npm run build:rollup` I get no error.

What am I doing wrong?

---

## Appendix: Root config and package.json

My vitejs config file for `root` in case that's helpful. Root uses `preact` and `components` are built in `React`.

```
// vite.config.js for root
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';

import { resolve } from 'path';

const config = {
  RecipeExplorer: {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/recipe-explorer.ts'),
    fileName: 'recipe-explorer',
  },
  RecipeList: {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/recipe-list.ts'),
    fileName: 'recipe-list',
  },
  RecipeDetailsLegacy: {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, './src/recipe-details.ts'),
    fileName: 'recipe-details',
  },
};

/** IMPORTANT:
 * We're using this LIB_NAME env variable so we can create multiple input and output files at build time.
 * At the moment this is a work around. Issue is here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4530
 * Once the above issue gets resolved, we can do away with this workaround.
 */
const currentConfig = config[process.env.LIB_NAME];

if (currentConfig === undefined) {
  console.warn(
    'LIB_NAME is not defined or is not valid. If you are running a build command LIB_NAME must be specified.',
  );
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: 'preact/compat',
      'react-dom': 'preact/compat',
      'react-dom/test-utils': 'preact/test-utils',
      'react/jsx-runtime': 'preact/jsx-runtime',
    },
  },
  plugins: [preact()],
  server: {
    port: 3010,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },
  build: {
    outDir: './dist',
    lib: {
      ...currentConfig,
      formats: ['cjs', 'es'],
    },
    emptyOutDir: false,
  },
});
```

I run `root` using `npm run dev` which is defined as `vite`:

```
// package.json for root
"name": "root",
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "vite",
...
}
...
```